# SwiftUI: Changing of button colors inside loop

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

My code looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedButtons: [Int] = []

    func updateButtons(value: Int) {
        if selectedButtons.count < 5 {
            if let index = self.selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value) {
                self.selectedButtons.remove(at: index)
            } else if selectedButtons.count < 5 {
                self.selectedButtons.append(value)
            }
        } else if selectedButtons.count >= 5 && selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value) != nil {
            if let index = selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value) {
                self.selectedButtons.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }

    func buttonColor(value: Int) -> Color {
        if let index = selectedButtons.firstIndex(of: value), index < colors.count {
            return colors[index]
        } else {
            return .white
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 7) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    self.updateButtons(value: index)
                }) {
                    Text("               ")
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                .background(self.buttonColor(value: index))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I want to change the color of buttons when selected according to colors array.In normal condition it works well, i can select button one by one and color changes. But If i click a button which is already clicked, then it becomes white as expected but other button color changes. I don't want to change color of other buttons when an already selected button is clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic fixed and the complexity reduced. Also, using different arrays to iterate over is unsafe, could get a crash if number of element differ. Use a struct model instead, to be safe. I've iterated over `colors` here for simplicity. You could replace it with a model if you'd like.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedButtonColors = [Color]()
    let colors: [Color] = [.blue, .gray, .green, .orange, .pink, .purple, .red]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Button(action: {
                    if let index = self.selectedButtonColors.firstIndex(of: color) {
                        self.selectedButtonColors.remove(at: index)
                    } else {
                        self.selectedButtonColors.append(color)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("               ")
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                .background(self.selectedButtonColors.contains(color) ? color : .white)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```